# batch file to loop through multiple subdirectories and copy/convert *.mts files to *.mp4 files

Tags: loops, for-loop, ffmpeg, subdirectory

I have the following batch script that loops through multiple directories and copies/converts *.mts files to *.mp4 files.

Script works but it copies alle the files to the same directory as the batch script. I want the script to convert/copy the files to the same directory they are in. How do I do this?

```
FOR /R %%A IN ("*.mts") DO ffmpeg -y -i "%%A" -c:v copy -c:a copy "%%~nA.mp4"
```

Comment: Replace `"%%~nA.mp4"` with `"%%~dpnA.mp4"`

Comment: Genius! Thanks alot.